# Autofac scope in web app in timer

Tags: autofac

I use autofac web integration and it works just great to resolve lifetime bound components. But one piece of code is invoked from timer and I'm getting null reference exception somewhere in Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerProvider.AmbientRequestLifetime.get(). Obviously it is because in timer there is no HttpContext and lifetime can not be obtained.
According to documentation I need to invoke "container.BeginLifetimeScope" and use this lifetime to resolve my component. But the component is quite low-level (networking, messaging) and it has no access to asp's Global object to access container object. Global object also has no access to so low-level component to inject container manually. 
To make the problem more difficult, this component can be invoked from web pages and need web request lifetime and it needs to be invoked from timer with manually constructed lifetime (or IDispose+using would be fine too).
How do I deal with situation when 2 types of life time scope is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things might help you get started in the right direction.

First, `builder.Register(...).InstancePerLifetimeScope()` will give you 'per-request' as well as 'per-custom-lifetime' scoping.

Second, if you're kicking things off under a timer, create a new lifetime scope manually at the entry point of the timer method wherever it happens to be:

```
void OnTimer()
{
    using (var timerScope = ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var someComponent = timerScope.Resolve(...);
        someComponent.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Here, the `ApplicationContainer` is the one you built in Global.asax when the web request started up - you need to find some way to get at it when the timer ticks.